# ggplot stacked bar chart issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(
        Type= c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"),
        value= c(14000, 2500, 145, 900))
```

I want to create a horizontal stacked bar chart. I have the following code:

```
 ggplot(data = d, aes(x=Type, fill=value) ) + geom_bar()
```

However this doesn't give me what I want. I just need one bar with the values stacked on top of one another. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's `library(ggplot2)`.

Comment: apologies, have edited to add more detail

Comment: What do you want to stack? The different types? Different values? Can you clarify what you expect on the x and y-axes? You could also draw the expected result in paint or whatever, or give a different example.

Comment: The question states that it is the values that I want to be stacked. If it's a horizontal stack the values would go across the x

Comment: If you have several x axis values ("t1", "t2", etc)  the bars will not be stacked. They will be only if they share the same x value.

Comment: Try this `d %>%
  mutate(Type2 = "type") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Type2, value, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip()`

Comment: @AntoniosK perfect, exactly what I was looking for. So I just needed to add a new variable which pulls all the values into one bar. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have several x axis values ("t1", "t2", etc) the bars will not be stacked. They will be only if they share the same x value. That is solved with the `dplyr` pipe, that creates a temporary variable `X`.

Thanks to [AntoniosK's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392209/ggplot-stacked-bar-chart-issue#comment93660101_53392209) for calling my atention to the OP's request for a *horizontal* bar.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


d %>%
  mutate(X = factor(1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = value, fill = value) ) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.2) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, there is no need to create a new variable. This also works:`ggplot(data = d, aes(x = "1", y = value, fill = value) ) + 
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) + coord_flip()`